# How did the Indian Appropriation Act of March 3, 1871 pass into law?

Tags: law, native-americans

Many histories (including the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Appropriations_Act#1871_Act)) state that Congress passed the Indian Appropriation Act of March 3, 1871. Did President Grant ever sign this law? I'm trying to figure out how it passed into law, and why it's called the "Indian Appropriation Act of March 3, 1871." (See the [Cornell Law School](https://www.law.cornell.edu/constitution-conan/article-2/section-2/clause-2/present-status-of-indian-treaties) code for example.)

For background, this Act prohibited the US Government from recognizing any new tribes or entering into any new treaties with the tribes.

Comment: "Normally, bills he neither signs nor vetoes within 10 days become law without his signature." _[Senate.gov](https://www.senate.gov/reference/glossary_term/presidential_signature.htm)_

Comment: "As the House debated the Appropriations Act of 1871, representatives hitched a rider denying Native sovereignty to what was otherwise a routine allocations bill. Even though the rider increased the House’s power in Indigenous affairs, the Senate approved the bill on March 3, 1871, and President Ulysses S. Grant signed it into law."_[ColoradoEncyclopedia](https://coloradoencyclopedia.org/article/indian-appropriations-act-1871)_

Comment: @MCW - that's great, if you make it an answer I can accept it. But why is it called the Act of March 3, 1871. Did Grant sign it on the same day?

Comment: [Indian Appropriations Act is a US law that was signed by President Grant on March 3, 1871 .](https://de.zxc.wiki/wiki/Indian_Appropriations_Act_(1871))